# How to speed up deploying time of jar in a remote server?

Tags: ssh, deployment, jar, executable-jar

Every time I want to test a java project written with Eclipse IDE I need to upload the `.jar file` (which is heavy) to a Testing Environment via SSH and that process takes almost `15 minutes`. It's uncomfortable to test any piece of code there because I have to wait that specific amount of time. The problem is that the upload speed cannot be increased (it belongs to the client). How can I reduce my deployment time for this kind of task?

> Testing Server: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

Answer (score 0):

Is Jar contains embedded appserver like tomcat or it is deployed to application library path ?

If you can de-compose the module & split into another jar (as jar creation is in your scope) it might help you to create small jar so that you can transfer the jar quickly.